# Basically the same code, but different thing happen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to make movement for my game, but I can't figure out sprinting and crouching.
I input this code, but it only crouches even tho there is basically no difference. is there an explanation?

```
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        isSprinting = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isSprinting = false;
    }

    if (isSprinting == true)
    {
        speed = 12;
    }
    else if (isSprinting == false)
    {
        speed = 8;
    }
```

And here I try to do the same thing, different key, and it moves the Character controller down by 0.8f. Somehow Crouching works, but sprinting doesen't.

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        isCrouching = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isCrouching = false;
    }

    if (isCrouching == true)
    {
        controller.height = crouchingHight;
        speed = 5;
    }
    else if (isCrouching == false)
    {
        controller.height = standingHight;
        speed = 8;
    }
```

And btw I use `controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);` to move my character, and I'm just trying to change the speed value.

Also, i use

```
public bool isSprinting = false;
public bool isCrouching = false;
```

To show me if the keys are registering and they are.

Comment: So you set the speed to 12 when sprinting, but when you are not crouching you set it back to 8

Comment: Well yea, but the problem is when I want to only sprint it doesn't. I get that I should add a thing that checks if I'm doing both at the same time, but first, I have to figure out why i can't sprint in the 1st place. And i set it back to 8 because it is the default walking speed.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 that is not wat is happing here, the code is just wrong.

Comment: @ConnorStoop Oh well, nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you set the speed to 12 when sprinting, but when you are not crouching you set it back to 8.\

you are basically doing this:

```
speed = 12;
speed = 8;
```

And expect the speed to be 12.

It might be better to use a modifier:

```
var speed = 8;
if (isSprinting)
{
    speed += 4;
}
if (isCrouching)
{
   controller.height = crouchingHight;
   speed -= 3;
}
```

Comment: oh yea, okay, so i should be changing the variables, i should be adding or removing  from them. aight. thank you.

Comment: I just tested it, and it just keeps adding 4 to the speed value, is there a way i could cap this?

Comment: You should set speed back to 8 before recalculating it.

Comment: So i set the sprint value just to be speed = 12, but crouch to be speed -=3, and somehow it all works. thank you.

Comment: Note that as `isCrouching` and `isSprinting` are `bool` (non-nullable), `== true` can be removed, and you can also get rid of the false-check (`else` is enough on its own)

Comment: Yep, to fast with the copy paste there will change that

Answer (score 1):

If your Boolean variables are "registering correctly" , maybe you could just make your movement code like  `controller.Move(move * speed * (isSprinting ? 1.5 : 1) * (isCrouching ? 0.5 : 1) * Time.deltaTime);` ?

Can you sprint and crouch at the same time? (A sprinting crouching character moves at 0.75 speed, sprint 1.5 and crouch 0.5)

Comment: I would guess crouch and sprint are exlusive though but this way you could easily adjust it to e.g. make the crouch overrule the sprint `controller.Move(move * speed * (isSprinting && !isCrouching ? 1.5 : 1) * (isCrouching ? 0.5 : 1) * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: I was in two minds about it, as if "sprint" is actually "move faster" I suppose your crouching character could have regular and fast creeping.. +1 for putting another bool in the ternary - it is better than nesting it